# Can close reason be revised?

Tags: discussion

[Why is Drupal 7 so slow?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/724/16495) is closed as not constructive. But it's duplicates and similar questions are posted pretty often. Now, users who post new ones [knows about old one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/87379/16495#comment-100979), but post anyway. My guess is that now there is no "not constructive" close reason, so they assume it's OK now.

Is there a way to have a currently valid close reason on this popular question? Or if it really is OK now (I doubt but oh well) should we have it reopened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to have a currently valid close reason on this popular question?

Yes, there is: The question should be re-opened, and closed again. I don't see any reason for doing that, though; that closing reason describes perfectly why the question was closed, and that is enough for the users to understand if they can ask a similar question.

> Now, users who post new ones knows about old one, but post anyway. My guess is that now there is no "not constructive" close reason, so they assume it's OK now.

[There isn't anymore a "not constructive" closing reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154), but that doesn't mean similar questions should be asked. In fact, there are two closing reasons that now replace that old one: *too broad* and *primarly opinion-based*. If a question can be closed for one of those reasons, it should be closed.

As for the question in question, the closing reason I would use nowadays is *too broad*, but it would still be kept closed.

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.